# Applozic : How to show the user first unread message rather than latest unread message?

Tags: android, ios, chat, applozic

This is a question w.r.t a chat app developed using applozic sdk. Currently in the chat detail page, the latest conversation is loaded. But I want to show the unread message that arrived first rather than the latest message arrived. How can it be achieved ?

Comment: Maybe what you can do is, when you are opening the chat details, you must be having something called, unread count which would indicate the number of messages that haven't been read yet. You can use this value to scroll your list to that particular message rather than scrolling to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, when you are opening the chat details, you must be having something called, unread count which would indicate the number of messages that haven't been read yet, correct. So you can use this value to scroll your list to that particular message rather than scrolling to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in onChildAdded, by getting the unSeenMessageCount as an int

```
if (unSeenMessageCount == 0) {

    rvChat.scrollToPosition(chatsAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

} else {

    rvChat.scrollToPosition(chatsAdapter.getItemCount() - unSeenMessageCount);
}
```